# Getting the correct data to be stored into temp table by comparing timerange

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently, I need to get the correct data to be inputted into temp table. There are 3 datetimes that I need to compare. However not all values are populated.

**Example-Assume that all dates are the same**

| Data1 | DateTime1 | DateTime2 | DateTime3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2020-08-24 14:00:00.000 | 2020-08-24 14:30:00.000 | 2020-08-24 15:30:00.000 |
| Second | NULL | 2020-08-24 13:00:00.000 | 2020-08-24 14:30:00.000 |
| Third | NULL | NULL | 2020-08-24 10:00:00.000 |

From the example, as you can see there are some null values in the columns. I need to get the value of **DateTime1** first, if null get the value of **DateTime2**. If **DateTime2** is also null, get **DateTime3**.

After getting the values, I need to compare it and see if it is less than 2 hours before putting it into the temp table.

**Example, If current time is 2pm = 1400Hrs**

**Final Output that I want to show**

| Data1 | DateTime1 | DateTime2 | DateTime3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2020-08-24 14:00:00.000 | 2020-08-24 14:30:00.000 | 2020-08-24 15:30:00.000 |
| Second | NULL | 2020-08-24 13:00:00.000 | 2020-08-24 14:30:00.000 |

Comment: why is the third row not showing? why did the second date in the first row change to 1400 from 1430? what is your current output?

Comment: _I need to compare it_ This refers to two specific values. Which ones from which rows do you compare?

Comment: @Eli Hi, the current output is the final output that i wanna show. I have change the Timing.

Comment: Hi @SMor I want to compare by 2 hours difference in  Datetime1 first, If null DateTime 2, if null DateTime3.

Comment: You didn't answer why the 3rd row isn't there. What does your current query look like? by current output, I meant to show what you're currently getting, not what you want to get

Comment: @Eli the OP explained that only rows in the last 2 hours should be returned. The third row in 4 hours in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to select the rows that have a datetime field in the last two hours. You can't use a function like `COALESCE` because that would prevent the use of any indexes that cover the columns. If you used eg :

```
WHERE COALESCE(DateTime1,DateTime2,DateTime3) >DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE())
```

The server wouldn't be able to use any indexes that cover the date fields and would be forced to scan the entire table to evaluate the function output and filter condition

A simple `WHERE` should work, without even checking for `NULL`, as any comparison with `NULL` fails :

```
declare @cutoff datetime=DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE())

SELECT .....
WHERE 
    DateTime1 > @cutoff 
    OR DateTime2 > @cutoff
    OR DateTime3 > @cutoff
```

If you want to compare only the *time* part, the only efficient way would be to extract the time part into separate fields using the `time` type and index them. Extracting the time part with , eg `cast(DateTime1 as time)` would prevent the use of indexing.

The following condition would work by scanning the entire table :

```
declare @cutoff time=cast(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()) as time);

SELECT ...
WHERE cast(COALESCE(DateTime1,DateTime2,DateTime3) as time) > @cutoff
```

Comment: Hi, from your example. I am able to think of solutions to resolve this problem. This is what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!